# How can i calculate percentages in pure css3 slider for 10 slides

Tags: css, slider

I have a project where a pure css3 slider is working with 5 images and keyframes calculation are as mentioned in the css script below. I want to increase that to 10 images and tried to play with keyframes but wasn't able to make it working. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

html:

```
 <div id="captioned-gallery">
     <figure class="slider">
          <figure> <img src="./files/auto1.jpg" alt=""> </figure>
          <figure> <img src="./files/auto8.jpg" alt=""> </figure>
          <figure> <img src="./files/auto3.jpg" alt=""> </figure>
          <figure> <img src="./files/auto4.jpg" alt=""> </figure>
          <figure> <img src="./files/auto5.jpg" alt=""> </figure>
          <figure> <img src="./files/auto1.jpg" alt=""> </figure>
     </figure>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
figure.slider {
     position: relative;
     width: 1000%;
     font-size: 0;
     animation: 30s slidy infinite;
}
 figure.slider figure {
     width: 10%;
     height: auto;
     display: inline-block;
     position: inherit;
}
 figure.slider img {
     width: 80%;
     height: auto;
}
 figure.slider figure figcaption {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
     color: #fff;
     width: 100%;
     font-size: 2rem;
     padding: .6rem;
}
```

CSS3 keyframes:

```
@keyframes slidy {
    0% { left: 0%; }
    10% { left: 0%; }
    25% { left: -100%; }
    45% { left: -100%; }
    50% { left: -200%; }
    70% { left: -200%; }
    75% { left: -300%; }
    95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of the size of your images, but below an example using images that are 150px wide. Hope this helps.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

figure.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 1500px;
  font-size: 0;
  display: flex;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite;
  margin: 0;
}

figure.slider figure {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  10% {
    left: -150px;
  }
  20% {
    left: -300px;
  }
  30% {
    left: -450px;
  }
  40% {
    left: -600px;
  }
  50% {
    left: -750px;
  }
  60% {
    left: -900px;
  }
  70% {
    left: -1050px;
  }
  80% {
    left: -1200px;
  }
  90% {
    left: -1350px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -1500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="captioned-gallery">
  <figure class="slider">
    <figure> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/0000ff" alt=""> </figure>
    <figure> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ff00" alt=""> </figure>
    <figure> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff0000" alt=""> </figure>
    <figure> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ffff" alt=""> </figure>
    <figure> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ffff00" alt=""> </figure>
    <figure> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff00ff" alt=""> </figure>
    <figure> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/0000ff" alt=""> </figure>
    <figure> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ff00" alt=""> </figure>
    <figure> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/ff0000" alt=""> </figure>
    <figure> <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x50/00ffff" alt=""> </figure>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: I just have to change image sizes